# Can anyone tell me why am I receiving a 'Fatal Error During Installation' message?

Tags: windows-7, coreldraw

I'm trying to install CorelDraw Graphics Suite X5.

Each time it appears to be installing, green progress line growing, percentage count until it reaches 99%. It pauses for quiite a long time then

> 'Your system has not been modified. To complete installation at another time please run setup again. 'Fatal Error during Installation'.

I've tried all the suggestions from both Corel and Microsoft but nothing has worked so far. Things like:

- cleaning out temp files,
- shutting down firewalls and virus checkers
- Disabling startup items and all services except MS.
- copied the files from the DVD to the HDD and installing from there

All to no avail.

To make sure there's nothing wrong with the files I have installed it on an older machine here running XP sp3. It installed without any issues. I also installed it onto my daughter's machine. She is running Windows 7 too. No issues there either.

My specs are as follows:

- Intel core i7 860 @ 2.8GHz 2.00 GHz
- 4 GB Ram.
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
- 500 GB HDD (with 300GB free)
- Gigabyte P55-UD3 Motherboard.

This is a genuine product straight out of the box. It says on the box that it is 32-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done all the standard failed install troubleshooting I would typically recommend.

Is there any sort of **installation log file** generated during install that could possibly provide additional clues on what the fatal error is about, exactly?

Can you check for files created during the install and see if any of them look like a log file of any kind?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I too thought a log file might provide a clue but I have no idea where to look. Or is it possible that logging has to be swithched on somewhere. There is nothing in the folder it created during install. There are a few files there but they all relate to the program.